# Creating mixed recursive macro to create a HTML templating DSL

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm new to Rust and even more to the macro engine, I'm trying to come up with a way of creating a DSL that I'll use for HTML templating that looks like the following,

```
h! {
  foo(
    "bar",
    tag_with_parens(),
    tag_without_parens,
    "some other expression",
    element(child),
  ), 
  "tags and strings can be siblings",
}
```

I've toyed around a bit but I'm not sure if it's even possible

```
macro_rules! h {
    // single idents and strings are matched here
    ($t:tt) => { h!($t(),) };
    ($t:tt( $($inner:tt),* )) => {h!($t($($inner),*),)};
    ($t:tt( $($inner:tt),* ), $($rest:tt),*) => {{
        // recursion with the contents of the tag            
        h!($($inner),*);
        // do something with the rest of the parameters
        h!($($rest),*);
    }};
}
```

In this simple example, I'm using `tt` since it matches both identifiers and the string literals but it breaks when the token is followed by the parenthesis because I imagine it considers it a separate token. I get `error: no rules expected the token (`. Also if I want to support not only passing a string but any expression it would have to be different

An extra credit assignment that would be my next step if I get the previous thing to work would be optional attributes as first argument. :)

```
h!(foo({ident="expr", bar}, "content"))
```

Comment: In my opinion, a compiler plugin is more suitable for this kind of use case. But unfortunately, it is not yet stabilized :(

Comment: In case you're not aware of the existing libraries in this space - [Horrowshow](https://github.com/Stebalien/horrorshow-rs) is written with `macro_rules` and [Maud](https://github.com/lfairy/maud) is a procedural macro. If you're totally stuck, maybe looking at their code could help you out. Totally understand if you're wanting to figure it out for yourself, though :)

Answer (score 0):

With the current Rust macro system it seems that it is not possible to implements such macro rule.

Simplifying, the needed rule sounds like:

the input is a list of different and intermixed patterns of the form `"literal"` and `tag(elem)`.

Zero or more literals `"a","b" ...` can be matched with the rule:

```
( $(label:tt),* )
```

Zero or more `tag(element)` can be matched with:

```
( $( $tag:ident ( $inner:tt ) ),* )
```

But how to define a rule that match such a sequence of different structured items?

Also a simple rule like this (zero or more `literal` followed by zero or more `tag(element))`:

```
$( $literal:tt ),*  $( $tag:ident ( $($inner:tt)* ) ),*
```

gives the error:

```
error: local ambiguity: multiple parsing options: built-in NTs tt ('literal') or ident ('tag').
```